# mysql update if all values not exists in same table else nothing

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a Table With multiple columns existing data already like

```
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
| id   | ref  |name          |role  | status  |
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
|    1 |   ab |Faizal        |adm   | 1       |
|    2 |   ab |Faizal        |      | 0       |
|    3 |   cd |Faizal        |usr   | 1       |
|    4 |   am |Agrim         |usr   | 1       |
|    5 |   xy |vishal        |usr   | 1       |
|    6 |   xy |vishal        |usr   | 0       |
|    7 |   ad |ankush        |usr   | 1       |
|    8 |   ad |ankush        |      | 0       |
|    9 |   mm |vishal        |oth   | 1       |
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
```

and I don't want assign a role to a user multiple time in table,Update should take action only when in the table **user** haven't the same **role** with same **status**. Like I tried that query

```
UPDATE roles t1
SET
  t1.role   = 'adm',
  t1.status = '1',
  t1.ref    = 'ab'
WHERE t1.id = 2 AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM roles t2
    WHERE t1.role = t2.role
          AND t1.status = t2.status
          AND t1.ref = t2.ref
)
```

**It Gives an Error**
I want after executing the query:

```
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
| id   | ref  |name          |role  | status  |
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
|    1 |   ab |Faizal        |adm   | 1       |
|    2 |   ab |Faizal        |      | 0       |
|    3 |   cd |Faizal        |usr   | 1       |
|    4 |   am |Agrim         |usr   | 1       |
|    5 |   xy |vishal        |usr   | 1       |
|    6 |   xy |vishal        |usr   | 0       |
|    7 |   ad |ankush        |usr   | 1       |
|    8 |   ad |ankush        |      | 0       |
|    9 |   mm |vishal        |oth   | 1       |
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
```

**nothing Changed** Because the given key data is already exist in table.

---

**Another Example:**
Run the query with other key data.

```
UPDATE roles t1
SET
  t1.role   = 'adm',
  t1.status = '1',
  t1.ref    = 'ad'
WHERE t1.id = 8 AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM roles t2
    WHERE t1.role = t2.role
          AND t1.status = t2.status
          AND t1.ref = t2.ref
)
```

after the executing the query table should :

```
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
| id   | ref  |name          |role  | status  |
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
|    1 |   ab |Faizal        |adm   | 1       |
|    2 |   ab |Faizal        |      | 0       |
|    3 |   cd |Faizal        |usr   | 1       |
|    4 |   am |Agrim         |usr   | 1       |
|    5 |   xy |vishal        |usr   | 1       |
|    6 |   xy |vishal        |usr   | 0       |
|    7 |   ad |ankush        |usr   | 1       |
|    8 |   ad |ankush        |      | 0       |
|    9 |   mm |vishal        |oth   | 1       |
+------+------+--------------+------+---------+
```

Keep in mind Conditions:

1. We can't INSERT or DELETE in table.
2. Can't update the rows where status=1

Comment: show us sample data and desire result  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Now I have updated my Question Plz check.. and revert me after reading the full question..

Comment: I don't understand your NOT EXIST and you have the unique id why do you bother to use the NOT EXIST ??

Comment: Plz read the question carefully. Hope you can understand.. Yes You can do It.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey ! Maybe the problem is your question and not the reader.

Comment: Dear @JeanDoux, Plz Read the Question carefully. Hope You have mind to understand the question

Comment: No i won't try, your are not listening on what we are saying, i will leave you alone with your bad jokes. Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the `update` statement any references to the records in that table still relate to the data as before the actual update, so it is normal that the sub-select does not consider the values you are inserting, but the values which are already there in the table.

Also this syntax with self referencing sub query is not allowed by MySql. Use a `left join` instead.

So list the literal values you are updating with, in that join condition as follows:

```sql
UPDATE    roles t1
LEFT JOIN roles t2 
      ON  t2.role = 'adm' 
      AND t2.status = '1' 
      AND t2.ref = 'ab'
SET
  t1.role   = 'adm',
  t1.status = '1',
  t1.ref    = 'ab'
WHERE t1.id = 2
 AND  t2.id IS NULL
```

That last condition corresponds to your `NOT EXISTS`. The `LEFT JOIN` will produce `NULL` values in all *t2* columns when the `JOIN` condition yields no results.

If you have a unique key constraint on those three fields, then you can achieve the same with the [`ignore`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) keyword:

```sql
UPDATE IGNORE roles
SET
  role   = 'adm',
  status = '1',
  ref    = 'ab'
WHERE id = 2
```

If this would result in a duplicate the statement will not do anything, nor report an error.

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: OK, please provide that info in your question, as you would already had that error with your SQL statement. Answer is now corrected and alternative added as well.

Comment: same error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'todo' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I already updated my answer. As to know the primary key: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: Thank a lot @trincot